# Query de facturas relacionadas a pagos correspondientes a esta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día , estoy buscando la manera de que salga así el resultado pero que me muestre solo los pagos correspondientes a las facturas. Ahorita lo que hice fue relacionar el socio de negocio con las facturas y los pagos a él, pero algo así quiero que me salga pero solamente las facturas que estén relacionadas a esos pagos:

```
Select T0.DocNum as Pagos ,
STUFF((SELECT ',' +convert(varchar(10),T1.DocNum) 
FROM OINV T1 
WHERE  T1.CardName = T0.CardName 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS FACTURAS
from ORCT T0 , RCT2 T3
where T0.DocDate >='20230301' and T0.DocEntry = T3.DocNum
```

Anexo un resultado de este query:

```
5055093
707395,707519,707531,630360,630402,630403,707698,630588,630589,707861,707973,630846
```

Siento que el error es en la igualdad dentro del stuff.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como podriamos saber que esta mal, si no sabemos que resultado queres tener, ni un ejemplo de tus datos?

Comment: Si no explicas qué información hay en cada tabla y como se relacionan, con esos nombres de tablas, ni idea de como escribir la consulta.